# Symfony2 2.7 cache

Tags: symfony, caching

Recently my app has received a substantial increase in visits per day.

This has resulted in times of 200-300 concurrent users on the web server arrives to collapse.

After researching why the server was collapsing, I have concluded that runs out of disk space to write the cache.

Currently I have 4G capacity allocated to the cache folder of the application. This folder takes to fill about 1 or 2 days. Therefore something is not working well.

I've been reading chapter Cache official Symfony book and I read that all default symfony cache is private.

I started to tell symfony which drivers must have a public cache in the development environment (localhost) shows me good header Cache-control, but when I run the controller output, shows me a bad header.

For example, the home page of my app should be cached in public for 30 minutes.

```
$response = $this->render('MyBundle:Folder:index.html.twig');
$response->setSharedMaxAge(2400);
```

Running the server in development mode from the console Google Chrome I can see that the response has this header:

> Cache-Control:public, s-maxage=2400

**Everything is OK up here.**

When I run the server in production mode, the header is not the same:

> Cache-Control:max-age=0, public, s-maxage=0

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: This happen always when you forgot to clear production cache after change something in code.

Comment: I understand you use the php based reverse proxy - AppCache. Is it enabled in your prod controller? In production, consider using a real reverse-proxy - like varnish. AppCache is a toy.

Comment: Im using opcache and i cant use varnish because my app runs with ssl

Comment: @malcolm i cleared prod cache before test.

Comment: @Borja did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: yes @beterthanlife In my case it was the varnish cache, which was doing a cache layer up symfony, because of this the headers I saw in the browser were "fake"